# Ajax async inside loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I use dbase.dll in PHP to transfer information from dbase files to MySQL.

I have 150 files to transfer. Each file as a name between 1000 and 5000.

I use PHP to transfer the files. But the request is made in jquery:

```
var Files = [1544,1548,1548,..];

 $.each(Files, function(i,val){

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: '../JC/Reaction.php?type=pes',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {SCADA: val},
            success: function(data){
                $('#Result').append(data);
            }  
        });    

    });

});
```

I had to set async to false for this action to be done properly.

The url '../JC/Reaction.php' is gets the val and perform the transfer for each file and echoes:

```
echo $val.' - Done';
```

The problem is that my brower crashes or nothing happens. I need to show in the browser on the 'Result' div the 'data' from the php like:
:

```
1544 - Done
1548 - Done
...
```

Any help would be nice!

Comment: since you are setting `async: false` it block the browser thread till each request is completed

Comment: i dont see why you need a synchronous request here

Comment: But should'n the browser show the information on success for each file?

Comment: is there a particular reason to use async false

Comment: If I don't set the async to false, the information shown is not correct. I think it's because each file takes like 10 seconds to be transfer and the information on the browser it's duplicated

Comment: shouldn't `data: {SCADA: val},` be `data: {'SCADA': val},` Else what kind of object is that?

Comment: Imagine I that the array val is val=[1554,3889] it should only show 1554 - Done / 3889 - Done. But it show duplicate 1554 - Done / 1554 - Done

Comment: {SCADA: val} work as well.

Comment: In any case, you should **queue** your requests.. I had done a similare question, by queing them you shouldn't have any freeze, if you perform them asyncronously

Comment: briosheje how can I queue them?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821064/stacking-multiple-ajax-requests-on-success-jquery , just use $.ajaxQueue and let it perform everything for you (check the first answer)

Comment: Try directly this: http://pastie.org/9452788 and tell us if it works :) . What is happening by using async: false is that once you perform a request, before performing the next one, your browser freeze until it is performed and does the same for the others. The result is that you see your browser freezing and, after some seconds, it comes back. If you perform the requests asyncronously, using async: false and by **queuing them**, then nothing will freeze and all the requests will be performed one after each other, giving you the result you're probably expecting :)

Comment: Thank you guys! I'll try your suggestions and ansewr you back!

Comment: briosheje:
Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxQueue is not defined

Comment: If you've found an answer to your question, post it as an answer below, and mark it "accepted" with the green checkmark to indicate this question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED**

```
var ajaxQueue = $({});

$.ajaxQueue = function(ajaxOpts) {  

    ajaxQueue.queue(function(next) {
        ajaxOpts.complete = function() {       
            next();
        };

        $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
    });
};

    $.each(Files, function(i,val){

        $.ajaxQueue({
            async: true,
            url: '../JC/Reaction.php?type=pes',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {SCADA: val},
            success: function(data){

                $('#Result').append(data);
            }  
       }); 

    });
```